# Possible WordPress .htaccess file contains suffix name?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to question about the Wordpress site `.htaccess` file. Possible this file with suffix name or must the `.htaccess` file doesn't contain any suffix name.

I have the Wordpress website my .htaccess file name contains some numbers as suffix name like this `.htaccess-1516661360`

Does must I remove the `-1516661360` name or must remain with the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: .htaccess is the default file name, should be only `.htaccess`

Comment: `htaccess` you mentioned is backup from your server side created at `Tue Jan 23 2018 02:49:20`. When backuping websites servers script copy your htaccess file with suffix of when it was created

Comment: @Samvel Aleqsanyan but my website don't contain `.htaccess` file only contains this backup file. Must what i do for create the main `.htaccess` file?

Comment: where is that file located?

Comment: @Samvel Aleqsanyan located on the Wordpress root folder

Comment: don't think, that it may do sense, if you delete it, but it's a bit strange, that website don't have `.htaccess` file in the main directory. try to re-save your permalinks in the dashboard of website. It should recreate new `.htaccess` file

Comment: @Samvel Aleqsanyan Thanks after saving permalink again and reload my website now shoed within my website root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htaccess` file with suffix name like `-1516661360` is backup of your real `.htaccess` file. It backuped from server side. You can see, when backup was done, if will convert `1516661360` [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to date.

If you'll go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` and click `Save changes`, then wordpress will create new `.htaccess` file for your permalinks structure, if it not exists.